# Asp.net MVC 5 Ajax call does not trigger method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I have problem that when I make an ajax call it does not reach the server. I've seen multiple post about this problem, but these posts dont work for me.
The weird thing that occurs is that, this code is working when I use the start with debugger in firefox it also hits the breakpoint then. But when I start the project without debugger it does not work on either firfox or chrome. what is going wrong?

this is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];            
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Agenda/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        title: v.Subject,
                        description: v.Description,
                        start: moment(v.StartDateTime),
                        end: v.EndDateTime != null ? moment(v.EndDateTime) : null,
                        color: v.ThemeColor,
                        allDay: v.IsFullDay
                    });
                    console.log("Pushing");
                })
                GenerateCalender(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        })

        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                aspectRatio: 1.5,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: events,
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                    var $description = $('<div/>');
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Starttijd: </b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm ")));
                    if (calEvent.end != null) {
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Eindtijd: </b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm ")));
                    }
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Beschrijving: </b>' + calEvent.description));
                    $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

And this is the method it needs to go in in the AgendaController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        var listofEvents = db.Events.ToList(); 

        return new JsonResult{ Data = listofEvents, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: First it should be `url: "/Agenda/GetEvents",` (but always use `Url.Action()` to generate your urls correctly. And what errors are you getting in the browser console.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed it to Url.Action() that didn't fix it. On chrome i get no errors. on firefox I get this error: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost:60628/Agenda/GetEvents
linenumber1, column1: I also can see that data is undefiend when I try to console log it

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I search through the error object nearly everything is undefiend... The weirdest thing of all is that I get a StatusCode 200 back with a response that is undefiend.

Comment: I already found the solution. The problem is not in the Ajax call... the problem was that the controller had an authorize on it and I forgot to make the GetEvents method allowanonymous. my bad sorry for wasting anyones time :')

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
    var listofEvents = db.Events.ToList(); 

    return Json (Data = listofEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: can you explain your answer a bit more, because or I dont fully understand it or it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution. The problem is not in the Ajax call... the problem was that the controller had an authorize on it and I forgot to make the GetEvents method allowanonymous. my bad sorry for wasting anyones time :') Should I delete this post? or should I take no further action?